# Determining cause of kernel panics

Tags: centos, kernel-panic

I have a HP DL360 G7 running CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) and suffering from kernel panics at random intervals and (to my eyes) random reasons. I've dug into the crash dumps using these as a guides: https://www.slideshare.net/PaulVNovarese/linux-crash-dump-capture-and-analysis and https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html

But the crash dumps seem to my eyes pointing to a different reason each time, i.e, I don't have the competency to understand crash dumps well enough to determine if they have any connection.

All the crash dumps that I have managed to get. Paste contains crash commands sys, bt and log of each dump.

**EDIT**
Due to suggested edits, I've pasted the `sys` and `bt` outputs of `crash` command. I'll keep the pastebin links as the `log` output of `crash` is too large to fit here.

Also adding that the server is running ECC memory and no indication of MCEs appear in logs so I'm not convinced that this is a faulty memory situation.

Any help or guide how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

https://pastebin.ca/3955184

```
      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2018-01-03-03:08:48/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 24
        DATE: Wed Jan  3 03:07:40 2018
      UPTIME: 28 days, 00:57:45
LOAD AVERAGE: 3.45, 2.43, 2.66
       TASKS: 714
    NODENAME: server
     RELEASE: 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Mon Dec 4 23:52:40 UTC 2017
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2666 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 72 GB
       PANIC: "general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP "
```

`bt`output

```
PID: 24892  TASK: ffff8808f9111fa0  CPU: 0   COMMAND: "python"
 #0 [ffff8808fba03910] machine_kexec at ffffffff8105c52b
 #1 [ffff8808fba03970] __crash_kexec at ffffffff81104a42
 #2 [ffff8808fba03a40] crash_kexec at ffffffff81104b30
 #3 [ffff8808fba03a58] oops_end at ffffffff816ad338
 #4 [ffff8808fba03a80] die at ffffffff8102e97b
 #5 [ffff8808fba03ab0] do_general_protection at ffffffff816accbe
 #6 [ffff8808fba03ae0] general_protection at ffffffff816ac568
    [exception RIP: inet6_csk_search_req+261]
    RIP: ffffffff81673385  RSP: ffff8808fba03b98  RFLAGS: 00010202
    RAX: 0000000000001c9e  RBX: 3932383931333431  RCX: ffff8807ed7918c8
    RDX: 00000000ffffffff  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: 00000000b1fa562e
    RBP: ffff8808fba03bb0   R8: ffff8807ed7918d8   R9: 0000000000000001
    R10: ffff8801f3ffc000  R11: 00000000b80dcf9c  R12: ffff880783d27178
    R13: ffff8808fba03bd0  R14: ffff8808ec21a9a8  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
 #7 [ffff8808fba03bb8] tcp_v6_do_rcv at ffffffff8166d73a
 #8 [ffff8808fba03c10] tcp_v6_rcv at ffffffff8166e1b2
 #9 [ffff8808fba03cc0] ip6_input_finish at ffffffff81643712
#10 [ffff8808fba03d00] ip6_input at ffffffff81643fe3
#11 [ffff8808fba03d58] ip6_rcv_finish at ffffffff81643518
#12 [ffff8808fba03d70] ipv6_rcv at ffffffff81643d99
#13 [ffff8808fba03df0] __netif_receive_skb_core at ffffffff81586f22
#14 [ffff8808fba03e60] __netif_receive_skb at ffffffff81587188
#15 [ffff8808fba03e80] process_backlog at ffffffff8158841e
#16 [ffff8808fba03ec0] net_rx_action at ffffffff8158799d
#17 [ffff8808fba03f40] __do_softirq at ffffffff81090b4f
#18 [ffff8808fba03fb0] call_softirq at ffffffff816b6b1c
--- <IRQ stack> ---
#19 [ffff880c1fcb3980] local_bh_enable at ffffffff81090017
#20 [ffff880c1fcb3990] __dev_queue_xmit at ffffffff815895a5
#21 [ffff880c1fcb39e8] local_bh_enable at ffffffff81090017
#22 [ffff880c1fcb39f8] ip6_finish_output2 at ffffffff816407b1
#23 [ffff880c1fcb3a78] ip6_finish_output at ffffffff81642cbc
#24 [ffff880c1fcb3aa0] ip6_output at ffffffff81642d77
#25 [ffff880c1fcb3b00] ip6_xmit at ffffffff81640039
#26 [ffff880c1fcb3ba8] inet6_csk_xmit at ffffffff81673059
#27 [ffff880c1fcb3c48] tcp_transmit_skb at ffffffff815e7c9f
#28 [ffff880c1fcb3cb8] tcp_connect at ffffffff815e97ed
#29 [ffff880c1fcb3d38] tcp_v6_connect at ffffffff8166c106
#30 [ffff880c1fcb3e08] __inet_stream_connect at ffffffff81605725
#31 [ffff880c1fcb3e80] inet_stream_connect at ffffffff816059d8
#32 [ffff880c1fcb3eb0] SYSC_connect at ffffffff8156a497
#33 [ffff880c1fcb3f70] sys_connect at ffffffff8156b29e
#34 [ffff880c1fcb3f80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff816b5089
    RIP: 00007f9e58f319d0  RSP: 00007ffece4029e0  RFLAGS: 00010246
    RAX: 000000000000002a  RBX: ffffffff816b5089  RCX: 00007f9e59144c28
    RDX: 000000000000001c  RSI: 00007ffece4030d0  RDI: 0000000000000003
    RBP: 0000000000000000   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 00000000032dfb60
    R10: 0000000000000006  R11: 0000000000000246  R12: ffffffff8156b29e
    R13: ffff880c1fcb3f78  R14: 0000000002b56510  R15: 00000000025950a0
    ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002a  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

https://pastebin.ca/3955185

```
      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2017-12-06-02:05:41/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 24
        DATE: Wed Dec  6 02:04:35 2017
      UPTIME: 15 days, 00:23:09
LOAD AVERAGE: 6.23, 4.95, 3.77
       TASKS: 726
    NODENAME: server
     RELEASE: 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2666 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 72 GB
       PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000000000008d0"
```

`bt` output

```
PID: 31570  TASK: ffff8811f9f9dee0  CPU: 11  COMMAND: "mysqld"
 #0 [ffff8800988ff340] machine_kexec at ffffffff8105c4cb
 #1 [ffff8800988ff3a0] __crash_kexec at ffffffff81104a42
 #2 [ffff8800988ff470] crash_kexec at ffffffff81104b30
 #3 [ffff8800988ff488] oops_end at ffffffff816ad338
 #4 [ffff8800988ff4b0] no_context at ffffffff8169d35a
 #5 [ffff8800988ff500] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff8169d3f0
 #6 [ffff8800988ff548] bad_area at ffffffff8169d714
 #7 [ffff8800988ff570] __do_page_fault at ffffffff816b02fc
 #8 [ffff8800988ff5d0] do_page_fault at ffffffff816b03a5
 #9 [ffff8800988ff600] page_fault at ffffffff816ac5c8
    [exception RIP: xfs_fs_destroy_inode+78]
    RIP: ffffffffc03d6f3e  RSP: ffff8800988ff6b0  RFLAGS: 00010202
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff8809781d00f4  RCX: 0000000000020100
    RDX: 000000000000000b  RSI: ffff8809781d01d8  RDI: ffff8809781d0000
    RBP: ffff8800988ff6c8   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 09781d01f00c0000
    R10: f669e55c17347c03  R11: 0000000000000000  R12: ffff8809781d0000
    R13: ffff8809781d0150  R14: ffff8811f97c2108  R15: ffff880cd7cbfe08
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
#10 [ffff8800988ff6d0] evict at ffffffff8121d658
#11 [ffff8800988ff710] iget_locked at ffffffff8121d83e
#12 [ffff8800988ff738] prune_icache_sb at ffffffff8121e834
#13 [ffff8800988ff7f0] vmpressure at ffffffff811f7451
#14 [ffff8800988ff878] do_try_to_free_pages at ffffffff811985a2
#15 [ffff8800988ff8f0] try_to_free_pages at ffffffff811987bc
#16 [ffff8800988ff988] __alloc_pages_slowpath at ffffffff8169fbcb
#17 [ffff8800988ffa78] __alloc_pages_nodemask at ffffffff8118cdb5
#18 [ffff8800988ffb28] alloc_pages_current at ffffffff811d1078
#19 [ffff8800988ffb70] alloc_skb_with_frags at ffffffff81573cbd
#20 [ffff8800988ffbc0] sock_alloc_send_pskb at ffffffff8156c9b9
#21 [ffff8800988ffc48] unix_stream_sendmsg at ffffffff8163aef0
#22 [ffff8800988ffcf8] sock_sendmsg at ffffffff8156a580
#23 [ffff8800988ffe58] SYSC_sendto at ffffffff8156a731
#24 [ffff8800988fff70] sys_sendto at ffffffff8156b2ce
#25 [ffff8800988fff80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff816b5089
    RIP: 00007fca94f07c0b  RSP: 00007fca7fed7308  RFLAGS: 00000202
    RAX: 000000000000002c  RBX: ffffffff816b5089  RCX: 00000000014c8a7c
    RDX: 0000000000004000  RSI: 00007fca6ebdb008  RDI: 0000000000000163
    RBP: 0000000000000000   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: 0000000000000040  R11: 0000000000000246  R12: ffffffff8156b2ce
    R13: ffff8800988fff78  R14: 00007fca6ebef238  R15: 0000000000004000
    ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

https://pastebin.ca/3955186

```
      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2017-11-14-04:21:30/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 24
        DATE: Tue Nov 14 04:20:23 2017
      UPTIME: 09:25:26
LOAD AVERAGE: 2.21, 1.47, 1.71
       TASKS: 788
    NODENAME: server
     RELEASE: 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 22:26:13 UTC 2017
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2666 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 72 GB
       PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008"
```

`bt` output

```
PID: 29737  TASK: ffff8811f6346eb0  CPU: 3   COMMAND: "kworker/3:0"
 #0 [ffff8811ac617948] machine_kexec at ffffffff8105c4cb
 #1 [ffff8811ac6179a8] __crash_kexec at ffffffff81104a32
 #2 [ffff8811ac617a78] crash_kexec at ffffffff81104b20
 #3 [ffff8811ac617ab8] no_context at ffffffff8169d2ba
 #4 [ffff8811ac617b08] no_context at ffffffff8169d350
 #5 [ffff8811ac617b50] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff8169d4ba
 #6 [ffff8811ac617b60] __do_page_fault at ffffffff816b017e
 #7 [ffff8811ac617bc0] __do_page_fault at ffffffff816b0325
 #8 [ffff8811ac617bf0] general_protection at ffffffff816ac548
    [exception RIP: xlog_write+772]
    RIP: ffffffffc03f8644  RSP: ffff8811ac617ca0  RFLAGS: 00010286
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff8811af615870  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 00000000000261a0  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: 0000000000005e6c
    RBP: ffff8811ac617d38   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: ffffc9000d576078
    R10: ffffc9000d57606c  R11: ffff8808f53ad800  R12: 0000000000007e00
    R13: 00000000000000d0  R14: 0000000000000000  R15: ffff880c9c7bb000
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
 #9 [ffff8811ac617d40] xlog_cil_push at ffffffffc03fa1f8 [xfs]
#10 [ffff8811ac617e10] xlog_cil_push_work at ffffffffc03fa395 [xfs]
#11 [ffff8811ac617e20] process_one_work at ffffffff810a881a
#12 [ffff8811ac617e68] worker_thread at ffffffff810a94e6
#13 [ffff8811ac617ec8] kthread at ffffffff810b098f
#14 [ffff8811ac617f50] save_rest at ffffffff816b4f58
```

https://pastebin.ca/3955187

```
      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2017-11-13-18:50:12/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 24
        DATE: Mon Nov 13 18:49:05 2017
      UPTIME: 10 days, 17:30:03
LOAD AVERAGE: 2.10, 2.43, 2.33
       TASKS: 785
    NODENAME: server
     RELEASE: 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 22:26:13 UTC 2017
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2666 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 72 GB
       PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000020"
```

`bt`output

```
PID: 27951  TASK: ffff8808f1b25ee0  CPU: 16  COMMAND: "php-cgi"
 #0 [ffff880113643a90] machine_kexec at ffffffff8105c4cb
 #1 [ffff880113643af0] __crash_kexec at ffffffff81104a32
 #2 [ffff880113643bc0] crash_kexec at ffffffff81104b20
 #3 [ffff880113643c00] no_context at ffffffff8169d2ba
 #4 [ffff880113643c50] no_context at ffffffff8169d350
 #5 [ffff880113643c98] mm_fault_error at ffffffff8169d674
 #6 [ffff880113643cc0] __do_page_fault at ffffffff816b027c
 #7 [ffff880113643d20] __do_page_fault at ffffffff816b0325
 #8 [ffff880113643d50] general_protection at ffffffff816ac548
    [exception RIP: xfs_free_eofblocks+91]
    RIP: ffffffffc03cf8db  RSP: ffff880113643e00  RFLAGS: 00010212
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff8811f3bdcec0  RCX: 000000000000000c
    RDX: 0000000000000fff  RSI: 0000000000000001  RDI: ffff8811f3bdcec0
    RBP: ffff880113643e58   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: ffff8811f3bdd010  R11: ffff880017c7b710  R12: 0000000000015a0b
    R13: ffff8808f7346000  R14: ffff8808f4ba00c0  R15: ffff880170ad2d20
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
 #9 [ffff880113643e60] xfs_release at ffffffffc03e7105 [xfs]
#10 [ffff880113643e88] xfs_file_release at ffffffffc03d65a5 [xfs]
#11 [ffff880113643e98] delayed_fput at ffffffff81202fc9
#12 [ffff880113643ee0] alloc_file at ffffffff8120322e
#13 [ffff880113643ef0] task_work_run at ffffffff810ad247
#14 [ffff880113643f30] do_notify_resume at ffffffff8102ab62
#15 [ffff880113643f50] int_with_check at ffffffff816b52bd
    RIP: 00007fd2f72abe90  RSP: 00007ffe5d25d848  RFLAGS: 00000246
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: 000055bac5cda3c0  RCX: ffffffffffffffff
    RDX: 0000000000000008  RSI: 0000000000000001  RDI: 0000000000000003
    RBP: 0000000000000000   R8: 000055bac5cda4a0   R9: 00007fd2fa6bb840
    R10: 000000000000000d  R11: 0000000000000246  R12: 0000000000000000
    R13: 0000000000000001  R14: 00007fd2e8771f58  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000003  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

https://pastebin.ca/3955188

```
      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2017-11-03-01:14:25/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 24
        DATE: Fri Nov  3 01:13:19 2017
      UPTIME: 3 days, 18:53:59
LOAD AVERAGE: 2.66, 2.58, 2.16
       TASKS: 744
    NODENAME: server
     RELEASE: 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 22:26:13 UTC 2017
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2666 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 72 GB
       PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)"
```

`bt` output

```
PID: 144    TASK: ffff8808faf52f70  CPU: 7   COMMAND: "kswapd1"
 #0 [ffff8808f9e0f7e8] machine_kexec at ffffffff8105c4cb
 #1 [ffff8808f9e0f848] __crash_kexec at ffffffff81104a32
 #2 [ffff8808f9e0f918] crash_kexec at ffffffff81104b20
 #3 [ffff8808f9e0f958] no_context at ffffffff8169d2ba
 #4 [ffff8808f9e0f9a8] no_context at ffffffff8169d350
 #5 [ffff8808f9e0f9f0] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff8169d4ba
 #6 [ffff8808f9e0fa00] __do_page_fault at ffffffff816b017e
 #7 [ffff8808f9e0fa08] __radix_tree_create at ffffffff81328a9e
 #8 [ffff8808f9e0fa60] __do_page_fault at ffffffff816b0325
 #9 [ffff8808f9e0fa90] general_protection at ffffffff816ac548
    [exception RIP: crc32_generic_combine+89]
    RIP: ffffffff8133db39  RSP: ffff8808f9e0fb40  RFLAGS: 00010207
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff88010b138008  RCX: dead000000000200
    RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: ffff88010b8bc570  RDI: ffff88010b138008
    RBP: ffff8808f9e0fb40   R8: e018000000000000   R9: 010b8bc5700c0000
    R10: fed6747d72e55c03  R11: 0000000000000000  R12: ffff88010b138000
    R13: ffff8808f47dbcb8  R14: ffff8811f973f108  R15: ffff880143a76b48
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0000
#10 [ffff8808f9e0fb48] file_has_perm at ffffffff812b752d
#11 [ffff8808f9e0fb88] evict at ffffffff8121d5e2
#12 [ffff8808f9e0fbb8] iget_locked at ffffffff8121d81a
#13 [ffff8808f9e0fbe0] iget_locked at ffffffff8121d8ce
#14 [ffff8808f9e0fc08] new_inode_pseudo at ffffffff8121e8c4
#15 [ffff8808f9e0fc70] ns_set_super at ffffffff81203878
#16 [ffff8808f9e0fca8] shrink_slab at ffffffff81195413
#17 [ffff8808f9e0fcc0] vmpressure_register_event at ffffffff811f7547
#18 [ffff8808f9e0fd48] balance_pgdat at ffffffff81199081
#19 [ffff8808f9e0fe20] kswapd at ffffffff81199323
#20 [ffff8808f9e0fe78] wake_up_atomic_t at ffffffff810b1910
#21 [ffff8808f9e0fea8] balance_pgdat at ffffffff811991b0
#22 [ffff8808f9e0fec8] kthread at ffffffff810b098f
#23 [ffff8808f9e0ff50] save_rest at ffffffff816b4f58

https://pastebin.ca/3955189

      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2017-10-30-07:14:38/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 24
        DATE: Mon Oct 30 06:13:31 2017
      UPTIME: 3 days, 06:21:18
LOAD AVERAGE: 1.03, 1.19, 1.36
       TASKS: 707
    NODENAME: server
     RELEASE: 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 22:26:13 UTC 2017
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2666 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 72 GB
       PANIC: "general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP "
```

`bt` output

```
PID: 32005  TASK: ffff8808f8bfeeb0  CPU: 4   COMMAND: "vtund"
 #0 [ffff8804623fb950] machine_kexec at ffffffff8105c4cb
 #1 [ffff8804623fb9b0] __crash_kexec at ffffffff81104a32
 #2 [ffff8804623fba80] crash_kexec at ffffffff81104b20
 #3 [ffff8804623fbac0] die at ffffffff8102e97b
 #4 [ffff8804623fbaf0] do_general_protection at ffffffff816acc3e
 #5 [ffff8804623fbb20] xen_int3 at ffffffff816ac4e8
    [exception RIP: memcmp]
    RIP: ffffffff8132b980  RSP: ffff8804623fbbd0  RFLAGS: 00010286
    RAX: ffff8801f3cd7048  RBX: 000000000000000a  RCX: ffff8806917dc048
    RDX: ffff8808fb333800  RSI: ffff8808f9f482e8  RDI: 0236303633043a00
    RBP: ffff8804623fbc40   R8: 0000000000000036   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: ffff88017fc03400  R11: 0000000000000000  R12: ffffffff8197ea30
    R13: 0236303633043a00  R14: ffff8808fb333868  R15: ffff8808a4f6a300
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0000
 #6 [ffff8804623fbbd0] insert_header at ffffffff8127cb99
 #7 [ffff8804623fbc48] register_leaf_sysctl_tables at ffffffff8127d28b
 #8 [ffff8804623fbc60] bstr_printf at ffffffff8132fb59
 #9 [ffff8804623fbd40] ipv6_add_dev at ffffffff8164784a
#10 [ffff8804623fbd70] addrconf_notify at ffffffff8164c9c9
#11 [ffff8804623fbd78] sysfs_slab_alias at ffffffff811df8d6
#12 [ffff8804623fbd88] dropmon_net_event at ffffffff815ab686
#13 [ffff8804623fbde0] trace_do_page_fault at ffffffff816b051c
#14 [ffff8804623fbe18] raw_notifier_call_chain at ffffffff810b68d6
#15 [ffff8804623fbe28] call_netdevice_notifiers_info at ffffffff8158306d
#16 [ffff8804623fbe50] register_netdevice at ffffffff8158c576
#17 [ffff8804623fbe88] __tun_chr_ioctl at ffffffffc07fca8e [tun]
#18 [ffff8804623fbf20] tun_chr_compat_ioctl at ffffffffc07fd10b [tun]
#19 [ffff8804623fbf30] compat_sys_ioctl at ffffffff8125d73b
#20 [ffff8804623fbf80] cstar_tracesys at ffffffff816b746c
    RIP: 00000000080d458c  RSP: 00000000fff1980c  RFLAGS: 00000246
    RAX: ffffffffffffffda  RBX: ffffffff816b746c  RCX: 00000000400454ca
    RDX: 00000000fff19840  RSI: 00000000fff19840  RDI: 00000000fff19860
    RBP: 00000000fff19878   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: 0000000000000000  R11: 0000000000000000  R12: 0000000000000000
    R13: 0000000000000000  R14: 0000000000000000  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000036  CS: 0023  SS: 002b
```

Comment: I suggest you directly put all the relevant information here. With proper formatting you can show all of them in a ordered manner without worrying that it would distract people from your main question.

Answer (score 1):

Do a memtest. Your issue is memory corruption. Memory errors can cause random, hard to diagnose errors.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/224501)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my answer to be less of a commentary.

Comment: Server is running ECC memory and should by my understanding exhibit Machine-check exceptions at least some times before failing. No indication of these in logs. Thanks.